# Expandable listView with checkboxes clicklistener

Tags: android, android-studio, checkbox, expandablelistview

I'm new in android development.I have create a expandable listview with checkboxes and textViews. What I'm trying to implement is that on checking the checkboxes a toast should be displayed with the corresponding text from textView but I'm not able to do that.

This code below doesn't work !
Is there any other way.I have done research and I'm still not finding the answer to my query

```
public class AddActivity extends Activity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
expandableListView=findViewById(R.id.expandableLIst);
        getDATA(); //This method works fine !
        expandableListAdapter=new Expandable_List_Adapter(this,listData_H,listData_Ch);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);

 expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(
                new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), listData_H.get(groupPosition)+" - "
                                +listData_Ch.get(listData_H.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition)
                                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return false;
                    }
                });

}
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  Try setting a log statement or breakpoint at the Toast line to make sure it's getting triggered.  If it's not, please provide more context as to where you're calling the above code.

Comment: I'm calling the code in onCreate method.

Comment: I have checked everything possible. Do you have any other suggestions? that might work

Comment: You need to apply checkbox listeners in your adapter where you create a childview.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16035299/1506585