# IndexOutOfBoundsException in expandable listview

Tags: android, expandablelistview, indexoutofboundsexception

According to this great answer [Android ExpandableListView with Checkbox, Controlling checked state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068668/android-expandablelistview-with-checkbox-controlling-checked-state) i made my class but i get an error to LogCat ArrayList.IndexOutOfBoundsException

mMyClass

```
public ArrayList<String> groups;
public ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> childs;
..........
ArrayList < ArrayList < Integer >> check_states =new ArrayList < ArrayList < Integer>>();

public class myExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {     
private ArrayList<String> groups;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> children;
private final Context context ;

public myExpandableAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> groups, ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> children) {
 this.context = context;
 this.groups = groups;
 this.children = children; }

public void setChildrenAndValues(ArrayList< ArrayList< ArrayList< String>>> c) {
    this.children = c;

    //initialize the states to all 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) {

        ArrayList<Integer> tmp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int j = 0; j < c.size(); j++) {
            tmp.add(0);
        }
        check_states.add(tmp);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
 {
     return true;
 }


@Override
public ArrayList<String> getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
 return children.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
 }

@Override
 public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
     return childPosition;
 }


@Override
 public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean     isLastChild,View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

String child = (String) ((ArrayList<String>)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition)).get(0);

 if (convertView == null) {
     LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.exp_list_child, null);
 }

 TextView childtxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_child1);

 childtxt.setText(child);   
 ///
 final View tick = findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
 if(check_states.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition) == 1)
     tick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 else
     tick.setVisibility(View.GONE);

 convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View v) {
         check_states.get(groupPosition).set(childPosition, 1);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+ check_states, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         tick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }
 });

 return convertView;
 }

@Override
 public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
     return children.get(groupPosition).size();
 }

@Override
 public String getGroup(int groupPosition) {
     return groups.get(groupPosition);
 }

@Override
 public int getGroupCount() {
     return groups.size();
 }

@Override
 public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
     return groupPosition;
 }

@Override
 public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

String group = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

if (convertView == null) {
     LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.exp_list_group, null);
 }

 TextView grouptxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListHeader);

 grouptxt.setText(group);

 return convertView;
 }

@Override
 public boolean hasStableIds() {
     return true;
 }

@Override
 public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
     return true;
 }

public void loadData(){
groups= new ArrayList<String>();
childs= new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>();

int proion_id= getIntent().getExtras().getInt("proionId");
  int length = dbAdapter.getDetailsOf(proion_id).size();
if(length >0) {

for (int i=0; i< length; i++)
{
    childs.add(new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>());
    childs.get(i).add(new ArrayList<String>());
    childs.get(i).get(0).add("A");
    childs.get(i).add(new ArrayList<String>());
    childs.get(i).get(1).add("B");
    childs.get(i).add(new ArrayList<String>());
    childs.get(i).get(2).add("C");

}

} else 
{childs.add(new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>());
childs.get(0).add(new ArrayList<String>());
childs.get(0).get(0).add("NO");}

}

    }
```

logcat

```
> 07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at com.techblogon.loginexample.ItemComments$myExpandableAdapter.getChildView(ItemComments.java:156)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:451)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-03 03:42:57.168: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: And?..........................

Comment: @deathember probably the problem is  c.size() but i can't find out how to solve it

Comment: Yeap, you're right. I think you need know about `debugging`? If not - google it. It will be help to you in this problem and for the future problems.

Comment: Look at your `check_states` in runtime. I'm sure about 0 size (0 items) of this variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may (not) see your log is telling you, that inside of getChildView you are accessing an array's first element when the size of it is actually zero.

I don't know why your array is not loaded with data but it may help if you add a check before accessing the array:

```
if (getChild(groupPosition, childPosition) > 0)
    String child = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).get(0);
```

Where your array not initialised at all it would throw a different error saying that you're trying to access a NullPointer.